# Refused to set unsafe headers ("upgrade" , "connection" , "sec-websocket-key")

Tags: angular, http, websocket

I am trying to implement handshake by hand using HttpClientModule in angular , My simple code is just sending an http get request with needed headers

```
makeConnection() {
        const headersOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'upgrade': 'websocket',
                'connection': 'upgrade',
                'sec-websocket-key': 'BOq0IliaPZlnbMHEBYtdjmKIL38='

            })
        };

        this.http.get(this.__url, headersOptions).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
```

When it does execute i am getting these errors

> Refused to set unsafe header "upgrade"
>
> Refused to set unsafe header "connection"
>
> Refused to set unsafe header "sec-websocket-key"

My back-end based on nodejs and i don't want to use WebSocket in angular.

Comment: Check out this https://snyk.io/test/npm/wild-angular

Comment: It's far away from my problem , Thanks

Comment: I’m sry. Good luck!